# Carregar todos as dependências dinamicamente

Tags: angularjs

No ficheiro ***index.php*** faço o include de todos os controllers:

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/ctrl_A.js"></script>
<script src="app/ctrl_B.js"></script>
<script src="app/ctrl_C.js"></script>
//etc...
```

Isso não é bom, uma vez que estou a carregar ficheiros javascript que não fazem falta, por exemplo, na homepage.

No .config da app estou a fazer referência ao controller da seguinte forma:

```
app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
      $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "view/login.html",
            controller: 'ctrl_A'
        })
//...
```

Como faço para que as dependências (controller, factory, directive, ect...) sejam carregadas dinamicamente sem declarar no index.php?

Comment: o angular tem o conceito de single page application (SPA) e não tem problema ele carregar todo o código logo de início. Tem ferramentas de automações de javascript que unem todos os seus javascripts e coloca em um único arquivo. Caso queira carrega-los dinamicamente pode tentar utilizar o requirejs . uma ferramenta que faz isso para você. Como não sou especialista em Angularjs vou esperar alguém mais experiente responder se o angular já faz isso.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a melhor forma seja usar o [angularAMD](https://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home). Ele basicamente une o AngularJS com uma definição de carregamento assíncrono de módulos Javascript chamada AMD, que faz justamente o que você espera.

Seu index ficaria apenas com um script desta forma:

```
<script data-main="app/app.js" src="app/libs/require.js"></script>
```

Transformar o seu código em módulos AMD traz benefícios a manutenibilidade do seu projeto não é uma tarefa difícil.